# Give internet Access to my local network users

Tags: networking, firewall, nat, local-area-network, pfsense

I have local network `10.10.10.0/24` and have pfsense. I use the pfsense for OpenVPN. Users connecting servers via vpn but users server ip addresses from local area network (ex. `10.10.10.30`) that is why do not have internet. How to give internet local area network users or specific users.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please coordinate with network administrator & Active director administrator looking after your organization network, network administrator will configure outbound policy in perimeter firewall to allow access for internal hosted server for 10.10.10.30 for internet access .For security reasons internet access for servers are not allowed in DMZ network . If permanent internet access provided then server will exploits attacks from hackers .

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but I needed a solution, the network side is fine. I would like any user to access the Internet via pfsense.

Comment: Yes solutions is check from your server where internet traffic is getting restricted do tracery from server